# Use List<T>ForEach to add element to HashTable

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable, ienumerable, enumeration

I have a list of string values that I want add to a hashtable or other array that can be accessed by key/index but cannot implement it. I have this working how I want but its ugly

```
        List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
        valueList.Add("1");
        valueList.Add("2");
        valueList.Add("3");

        Hashtable p = new Hashtable();


        valueList.ForEach(delegate(string f) { p.Add(valueList.FindIndex(v => v == f), f); });
```

EDIT: After James reminded me that a List will return values by index I went with a List and this is what I have ended up with

```
valueList.ForEach(f => sequenceList.Add(int.Parse(f)));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Build a hashtable of out of the List mapping the index to the key?

Comment: I am struggling to see the benefit of what it is your doing? Why not just leave it as a List if you are just indexing it?

Comment: Have decided to leave it as a list, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
valueList.ForEach(x => htable.Add(valueList.FindIndex(y => y == x), x));
```

Although, there's really no reason *not* to use a `for` here

```
for (var index = 0; index < valueList.Count; index++)
{
    htable.Add(index, valueList[index]);
}
```

It's more lines of code, but it's more straightforward and will perform much better (findIndex is far less efficient than using the `index` from the for statement).

Comment: I'd go more straightforward than that - query valueList.Count directly in the for loop. The performance difference will be negligible and the code is simpler.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Good point.  I consolodtated the for loop code down to two lines.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it compiled, it wouldn't work - calling `GetEnumerator().Current` will always fail because it'll give you a *new* iterator positioned before the first item.

What do you want the key for each item to be? If it's just its position within the list, I don't see the benefit that gives you over a list (which is already indexed by `int`). However, you can do it like this (assuming that `valueList` is a `List<string>`:

```
var dictionary = valueList.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.item);
```

Adding it to an existing dictionary, I'd just do:

```
for (int i=0; i < valueList.Count; i++)
{
    dictionary[i] = valueList[i];
}
```

Not *everything* has to be done with lambdas :)

Note that this won't have quite the same effect as using `FindIndex` if you have repeated values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the strings to be the keys and the index to be the value:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

for (var i = 0; i <= valueList.Count; i++)
{
    ht.Add(valueList[i], i);
}
```

Otherwise switch the ht.Add parameters around. However, if that is the case you would be best just to leave it as a List < string >.

Comment: Yup that would work, just wondered if the built in List.ForEach could do the same thing

Comment: If you want it to have ht[index] returns a string, then I would suggest you use Mitch Wheat's solution. If it is the opposite i.e. ht[string] returns index then I suggest mines.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"w", "y", "u", "i", "n"};

HashSet<string> hset = new HashSet<string>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ForEach for this is not efficient, as you have to use FindIndex to find out where you are. It works, but you will do a lot of extra work:

```
valueList.ForEach(x => htable.Add(valueList.FindIndex(y => y == x), x));
```

It's better to just use a regular loop, so that you get the index without having to seek through the table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valueList.Count; i++) {
   htable.Add(i, valueList[i]);
}
```